# Using custom membership provider in a wcf service error

Tags: wcf, membership-provider

I have an asp.net mvc 4 web application where I have created a custom membership provider (inheriting from MembershipProvider base class). In the same solution but in another project I have a wcf service where I want to authenticate a user using the ValidateUser method from my membership provider (which is called KinematMembershipProvider)

This is my interface of the service

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IKinematService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password);
}
```

and the actual service

```
public class KinematService : IKinematService
{
    public bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        KinematMembershipProvider membershipProvider = (KinematMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["KinematMembershipProvider"];
        return membershipProvider.ValidateUser(username, password);
    }
}
```

and this is my app.config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--configSections-->
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <!--appSettings-->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--connectionStrings-->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="KinematDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=KinematDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--system.web-->
  <system.web>
    <!--compilation-->
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <!--membership-->
    <membership defaultProvider="KinematMembershipProvider">
      <!--providers-->
      <providers>
        <add name="KinematMembershipProvider" type="Kinemat.Web.Infrastructure.KinematMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="KinematDbContext" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" passwordFormat="Encrypted" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <!--system.serviceModel-->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--services-->
    <services>
      <service name="Kinemat.WebServices.KinematService" behaviorConfiguration="ProviderServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:52174/WcfServices/Kinemat" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MembershipBinding" 
                  contract="Kinemat.WebServices.IKinematService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <!--bindings-->
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MembershipBinding">
          <security mode ="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType ="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!--behaviors-->
    <behaviors>
      <!--serviceBehaviors-->
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ProviderServiceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
                                    membershipProviderName="KinematMembershipProvider" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <!--entityFramework-->
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

When I run my service I get the following error **System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Kinemat.Web.Infrastructure.KinematMembershipProvider' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.**

I cannot figure out why it is trying to search in System.Web assembly. Please do you have any suggestion? Please ask for any additional information if you need. Thank you.

Comment: Under `<providers>`, have you tried adding the `<clear />` element before the `<add..>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trying to find it in the `System.Web` assembly because you have not specified in the configuration where it should actually search for your provider. Try amending your configuration to include the assembly name like below:

```
<providers>
    <add name="KinematMembershipProvider" type="Kinemat.Web.Infrastructure.KinematMembershipProvider, Assembly.Name.Where.Provider.Resides" .../>
</providers>
```

Comment: OP does define it in the config file.

Comment: Am i missing something? i can only see the membership provider type name specified `type="Kinemat.Web.Infrastructure.KinematMembershipProvider"` without the actual assembly name.

Comment: Yes that was the problem...Thank you very much